# Laptop occasionally won't run on battery power until I remove and reinstert the battery

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power

I have a Toshiba Satellite S55-B5280.

Occasionally, the laptop will stop running on battery power. Meaning, if the AC adapter is unplugged, the laptop won't turn on; while the laptop is turned on, if I unplug the AC adapter, it shuts down immediately.

Once it gets into this state, it continues until I remove and reinstert the battery, which reliably fixes it. After the problem is fixed, the laptop runs fine on battery and the battery life is normal.

At first I suspected it may be an issue with the physical connection at the battery connector, but the laptop sometimes enters this state while sitting undisturbed on a table.

What could be the cause? Is it more likely to be a fault in the battery, the laptop's power circuitry, or the battery connector?

**edit:** `upower` shows a battery voltage of 16.7 V. Laptop has stopped running on battery entirely.

**edit:** I tested the battery with a multimeter, and 16.7 V is accurate. I'm not sure if that rules out the battery as a problem or not.

I tested the two fuses PF1 and PF2 (white rectangles with a "Y" on them in the photo below), and they are both short (which I assume means they are good):

[image]

You can see above one of the fuses, there is a zero ohm link, possibly named PR74. This connects to the pulldown to enable the battery. If I insert the battery (AC power unplugged) and measure the voltage at PR74, it is 3.1 V. Then, I try pressing the laptop power button, and PR74 remains 3.1 V. I'm not sure if this might indicate a problem.

PR74 connects to R671 (bottom right), which is 1kohm. I'm not sure where it goes after that.

Comment: Is there any correlation with heat? There may a temperature-sensing circuit being tripped that does not reset without removal and reinsertion of the battery. Batteries typically have these sensors, and the OS *can* query this ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372698(v=vs.85).aspx ) and shut off the battery circuit based on temperature.

Comment: @Yorik That's an interesting theory. I think there is no correlation with heat, because it sometimes happens when the laptop is sleeping (so, rather cold) and sometimes while I'm using it (warm, but not too hot).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there is an issue with the motherboard (laptop's power circuitry). When issues like this appear, I call up warranty service and describe the problem. Their only answer is to replace the motherboard.

Is your laptop still under warranty? Are there any firmware updates for the motherboard?

Comment: I see. That's too bad. I will look into it.

Comment: keep in mind that "replace the motherboard" is generally the service center's default response when they have no idea what the problem is